# Using interface to process a file and return in a different format

Tags: java, file, interface

I'm working on an assignment where the program has to process a file and read every line then print it out in all caps. I'm pretty sure I have most of it written out, however, I am having trouble with my main method. I am supposed to call my go method in my FileProcessor class and have it use the StringProcessor interface to call my Upper class. I'm using an interface because I will be adding other classes later, but for now I am having trouble with implementing it all in my Driver class.

How do I declare a StringProcessor object in my Driver class and how can I use it so that it would create the file in all caps?

Here's my code so far:

**Driver.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import java.io.File;

public class Driver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            Scanner in = null;
            File selectedFile = null;

            if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {
                selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile(); 
                in = new Scanner(selectedFile);
                FileProcessor filePro = new FileProcessor(selectedFile);

                while (in.hasNext())
                {
                    String line = in.next();
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**FileProcessor.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class FileProcessor
{
    private Scanner in;

    /**
     * Processes file to be able to use
     * @param f file to be processed
     */
    public FileProcessor(File f) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public void go(StringProcessor s) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        while (in.hasNextLine())
        {
            s.process(in.nextLine());
        }
    }
}
```

**StringProcessor.java**

```
public interface StringProcessor
{
    void process(String s);
}
```

**Upper.java**

```
public class Upper implements StringProcessor
{
    public void process(String s)
    {
        System.out.println(s.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if I didn't post the best question, but I am struggling with this subject and would like to learn it because right now I'm teaching myself java.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare an Upper object instead, since you cannot directly create StringProcessor objects, as it is an interface. But as Upper extends StringProcessor, your Upper object will be a StringProcessor object too.

You can either use:

```
StringProcessor object = new Upper();
```

or

```
Upper object = new Upper();
```

Therefore, you would need to create as many objects as caps:

```
Upper object1 = new Upper();
Lower object2 = new Lower();
```

or also:

```
StringProcessor object1 = new Upper();
StringProcessor object2 = new Lower();
```

You would then use

```
filePro.go(object1);
```

and

```
filePro.go(object2);
```

Comment: How would I implement that to my Driver method? Would filePro be my implicit parameter and object be my explicit for go?

Comment: I edited my answer. You would either use object1 and object2 as StringProcessor or as Upper, Lower. Both options are possible and correct.

Comment: I figured it out, thank you. But the problem I'm running into now is that it's giving me an error saying that void is not allowed but my interface is supposed to be void.

Comment: As I understand, your interface is not void. What do you mean exactly by "my interface is supposed to be void"? Could you please copy the exact error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Add the line:

```
filePro.go(new Upper());
```

after you created filePro.

UPDATE:

```
StringProcessor sp = new Upper();
while (in.hasNext())
{
     String line = in.next();
     sp.process(line);
}
```

Comment: This worked, however, how do I get it to print out every line in all caps using this? It said my go method does not return if it's void.

Comment: Yes, my Upper class is just return s.toUpperCase(); but how do I call it in my Driver class?

Comment: See my update above. Note however that if you do this, you won't need the go method in your FileProcessor, which would also make the whole class irrelevant: you could use Scanner instead.